# How to get bigger image from .ico file?

Tags: php, favicon, ico

I'm working on trying to download and save a favicon(.ICO) from a website using php. I want to convert this ico file to a png.

If I understand this correctly, a single .ICO file can store different image resolutions, like 16x16 and 32x32 ([google's favicon](http://www.google.com/favicon.ico) is an example of this). My question is, is there a way to choose which ico file to convert?

Currently I can download the file

```
$image = file_get_contents('http://google.com/favicon.ico');
$saved_file = fopen("favicon.ico", "w");
fwrite($saved_file, $image);
fclose($saved_file);
```

This code downloads and saves a file called `favicon.ico`.

Then when I run this line of code

```
var_dump(getimagesize('favicon.ico'));
```

I get this output

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  int(16)
  [1]=>
  int(16)
  [2]=>
  int(17)
  [3]=>
  string(22) "width="16" height="16""
  ["bits"]=>
  int(32)
  ["mime"]=>
  string(24) "image/vnd.microsoft.icon"
}
```

So my question is, how do I programmatically access the other icon sizes? I can clearly see them using Preview on my mac, but not within php.

Any ideas?

Comment: php has no native .ico support. you'd either have to write a parser from the ground up, or use external libraries/tools to do it for you. in fact, php has no native image support anyways. there's imagick, and gd, both of which are external libs that happen to have php bindings.

Comment: why don't you use font icon

Comment: Why dont use best answer flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many times I found your answer ;)
You can use this class: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2369-PHP-Extract-graphics-from-ico-files-into-PNG-images.html

The sample code:

```
<?php
include 'class.ico.php';
$ico = new Ico('http://google.com/favicon.ico');

$im = $ico->GetIcon(0); //For get first image
//$im = $ico->GetIcon(1); //For get second image
//$TotalIcons = $ico->TotalIcons(); //for get total numbers of images in icon

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Output:
For first image 16x16 separate will be in output: [image: png-16x16]
For second image 32x32 separate will be in output: [image: png-32x32]

And also, this class have a great method for get all icon in single image. see:

```
<?php
include 'class.icothumb.php';
$ico = new IcoThumb('http://google.com/favicon.ico');
$ico->max_size = 128;
$ico->use_diferent_depths = false;
$ico->GetThumb(4);
?>
```

The output is perfect as single image:
[image: all icon as single image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free grabicon.com service to retrieve png-formatted favicons in the size you request. It handles resizing for you, and creates unique default icons for sites that don't have a favicon.

This example pulls Wikipedia's 32-pixel PNG favicon:

```
http://api.grabicon.com/icon?domain=wikipedia.org&size=32
```

This is also a lot faster than retrieving the icons yourself, since they're cached from other users' requests. Pulling icons from scratch typically takes 4-6 seconds each to follow page redirects, check the default location and meta tags, etc.

Full disclosure, I'm the creator, but I think this is what you need, and it's free.

Comment: Grabicon.com charges now.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/lordelph/icofileloader provides more up-to-date support for processing .ico files in PHP than the PHPclasses link in Nabi's answer

Here's an example which would extract all the images in an icon:

```
$icon = $loader->fromFile('/path/to/icon.ico');
foreach ($icon as $idx=>$image) {
     $im=$loader->renderImage($image);

     $filename=sprintf('img%d-%dx%d.png', $idx, $image->width, $image->height);
     imagepng($im, $filename);

     printf("rendered %s as %s\n", $icon->getDescription(), $filename);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

how do I programmatically access the other icon sizes?

you just answered your own question. when you use `var_dump(getimagesize('favicon.ico'));`
you can get `"width="16" height="16""` information of the image.

if you have these `.ico` files in a directory somewhere, go through each of the images using php `scandir` function that use `getimagesize` function to get the icon sizes.

Comment: No, I thinks the means was how access to different images in single `.ico` file. (we know an .ico file is a multiple images file)